# Modal is hidden but "history" of the modal is kept

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I hope I can explain my problem propely because it's quite confusing and I couldn't find an answer in 3 hours...

## Description

First of all I am developing a carpool website for my school. Therefore it is possible for users to book tours offered by other users.

If user A decides to book B's tour he clicks a button. This button opens a Bootstrap Modal where A has to confirm the booking.

If he accepts the Booking the tour should be booked (at the moment there is an alert as an info for me). If the booked tour is the first tour booked in his session, then everything works fine.

Now User A wants to book another tour, he clicks the button and a modal shows up (just like it should) he, again, confirms the booking.

Now to the real problem.

After confirming his second booking there will be two alerts, the first one with the tour data from the first booking and afterwards an alert with the data of the current booking.

If A tries to book a third tour, there will be three alerts and so on...

This makes it impossible for me to handle the bookings and leads to various problems in my database.

## What have I tried?

I've already thought for some time, made different outputs, tried to vary the closing methods of my modal (even removing it completely => quite stupid I know now), read throught the documentation and tried other solutions I found on the web but none of them worked for me.

The highlighting does not work, sorry for that :/
So in var mymodal I save the modal that is shown.

## Code explanation

In mymodal I "save" the modal I want to display (works always)
The button "ConfirmBooking" is my, surprise, surprise, confirm button to confirm the booking.

The alert "alertLogged" is also displayed correctly and fades away after 3 seconds

As stated in the code all alerts in and after the setTimeout method are called again and again with the new one attached to that row (always an seperat alert).

The bookTour() method is working, the only probmelm is that it is called for all old bookings everytime a new one is done, therefore I've commented it out

```js
var mymodal = $("#ModalEingeloggt");//Modal zum bestätigen setzen
mymodal.find(".modal-body p").html("Wollen sie wirklich \"" + fahrt + " Uhr\" für ihr Kind buchen? <br> Der Fahrer Ihres Kindes ist "+fahrername +".");
modal.modal();
$("#ConfirmBooking").on("click",function(){//wenn angenommen wird
    mymodal.modal('hide');
    $('#alertLogged').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>"+fahrt+" wurde bei "+fahrername+" gebucht!</div>");
    $('#alertLogged').addClass("show");
    setTimeout(function() { //With every new Modal all the alerts from the old Modals are called aswell
        $("#alertLogged").removeClass("show");
        alert(fahrername+"-"+fahrt+"-"+fahrttag+"!");
        //bookTour(fahrername,fahrt,fahrttag);
    }, 3000);
    alert(fahrername+"-"+fahrt+"-"+fahrttag+".");
    //bookTour(fahrername,fahrt,fahrttag);
});
```

I hope someone can help me, because I've literally no idea how to solve this problem...

Thanks in advance for every second you sacrifice for me.

It is my first big project so please don't be too harsh if it is a really stupid question...

Comment: Can you provide minimal working example? The code snippet you provided is not sufficient to understand the problem.

Comment: @Dima Vishnyakov I think I can't because no other code is involved in the problem, if you want to, I can show the structure of the modal itself...

Comment: If you recreate the modal each time, it sounds like you're attaching the event to the same element again, and when you click it all the handlers are fired including previous ones. If I could suggest trying to create a minimal example in jsfiddle.net for example - just the very basics, it doesn't have to be anything fancy.

Comment: Okay I will try but it will take some time I guess 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, you're attaching an event handler each time you open the modal dialog, and you can verify this in chrome by selecting the button element and looking at the list of handlers in the Event Listeners tab under click - the list grows each time. Closing the modal doesn't destroy the elements inside the modal, it just hides them. The easiest solution is probably to detach the event handler (with .off() for instance) when closing the modal dialog.

Comment: OMFG thank you so much for helping me. Just thanks. I'm not that good in English so it's hard for me to show how thankful I am.